# C++ MPI multi receiving

Tags: c++, mpi

I have problem with MPI with C++. I want to read from txt file line by line and depend on mount of nodes, i want to send read lines to them one by one in loop.

My question is, how to receive data, when i don't know how many times i will send data for node?
Can i tell somehow in send function, that i will send another data to node and handle this information on node side?

for example:

```
 while (std::getline(file, line)) {
           MPI_Send(&some_data, 1, MPI_INT, some_node, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
```

and then i want to receiveing data in another node until sending node will tell "ok, this is the last send", something like this:

```
while (will_send == 1) {
            MPI_Recv(&some_data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }
```

Comment: Well, in general it is not MPI related, you design some protocol and follow it. One approach would be to send number of items upfront, another would be to reserve some message for end-of-the-line characters, pretty much like line with words in editor

Comment: You do not want to send a message for every line of stdin. Buffer your data and send at least a page at a time.

Comment: what does "depend on mount of nodes" mean?